# Extjs grid special character issues

Tags: extjs, special-characters, extjs3, extjs-grid

I am using ExtJS 3, I am entering special characters like "&,<,>" in the Textfield of a grid cell, and when I release that cell then that special character converts into an empty string. It seems like grid does not support special characters (&,<,>).

The code below runs while I edit the grid cell.

```
new Ext.grid.GridEditor(new Ext.form.TextField({
  cls:'grid-field-editor' ,
  allowBlank: field.toLowerCase() !== "wr_default",
  blankText:resources.getMsg("required_field") ,
  regex:new RegExp(Ext.util.Format.trim("^(?!@#$)([undefined]|[!%* |^=+$'-,':.~]){1,2}$")),
  regexText:resources.getMsg("Value does not match parameter.") + " " + Ext.util.Format.trim("^(?!@#$)([undefined]|[!%*?|^=+$'-,':.~]){1,2}$")
}))
```

Comment: Could you show the code ?

Comment: @FrankPentangeli Thanks for the reply

 Below  code run while edit the gird cell.   

new Ext.grid.GridEditor(new Ext.form.TextField({cls:'grid-field-editor'
 ,allowBlank: field.toLowerCase() !== "wr_default"
 ,blankText:resources.getMsg("required_field")
 ,regex:new RegExp(Ext.util.Format.trim("^(?!@#$)([undefined]|[!%*?|^=+$'-,':.~`]){1,2}$"))          
 ,regexText:resources.getMsg("Value does not match parameter.") + " " + Ext.util.Format.trim("^(?!@#$)([undefined]|[!%*?|^=+$'-,':.~`]){1,2}$")}))

Comment: This is a bug, if you can't upgrade to ExtJS 5, you should apply a patch. Could you share with us the fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor (choose your version, should be 3.4) ?